# How can $\hat p = - i \hbar \partial_q$ be derived starting from the definitions of $\hat q$ and $\hat p$ in terms of creation/destruction operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, harmonic-oscillator, commutator

Consider the position and momentum operators $\hat q$ and $\hat p$, defined respectively in terms of creation and destruction operators in the usual way:
$$
\hat q = c (\hat a + \hat a^\dagger), \qquad
\hat p = \frac{i\hbar}{2c} ( \hat a^\dagger - \hat a), \tag 1
$$
for some constant $c$, where $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$ satisfy the canonical commutation relations:
$$ [\hat a, \hat a^\dagger] = 1, \qquad [\hat a,\hat a] = [\hat a^\dagger, \hat a^\dagger] = 0. \tag 2$$
If follows immediately that, as expected, $[\hat q, \hat p] = i \hbar$.

My question is now: starting from these definitions of $\hat p$ and $\hat q$, how can I derive the common relation $\hat p = -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial q}$, or some equivalent version of this relation?
In other words, how can I compute the value of $\langle q | \hat p| \psi \rangle$, or equivalently of $\langle q| \hat p | q' \rangle$?

If I try to simply compute this using the definition of $\hat p$ given in **(1)** I get nonsensical results, I'm gessing because of $|q \rangle$ being not normalized eigenstates. What method should then be used in this context?

Comment: ...I might need to get used to this gold badge. If the marked question doesn't answer your question, ping me and I will reopen the question.

Comment: Once you arrive at the commutation relations for q and p, the question is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45248/. Maybe there is a more direct way.

Comment: @ACuriousMind why do you say it's a duplicate of that question? There they basically *start* from $\hat p =-i \hbar \partial_q$, while my question is how to get there starting from the definition of $p, q$ in the context of a quantum harmonic oscillator

Comment: @jinawee I see. Then we are basically saying that given the CCR the only possibility is that $p=-i\hbar \partial_q$ (up to a function added to this). But then I wonder, is there no way to reach this result that does not involve knowing the solution in advance or employing highly non-trivial math?

Comment: Hm, yeah, you're right, the one jinawee linked is a better fit. The rigorous statement of "the momentum operator must be the derivative in the position representations" is the Stone-von Neumann theorem, I don't think you'll get to that without some sort of "highly non-trivial math". Quantum mechanics *is* mathematically non-trivial ;)

Comment: @ACuriousMind true. But still there are often hand-wavy, more physical arguments that can be made to more simply get results. For example, I wonder if in the present case one could consider an harmonic oscillator constrained in a finite space, which should make the eigenvalues of $q$ discrete and hence maybe remove some difficulties?